# Does faith precede miracles or do miracles precede faith?

Tags: john, matthew, contradiction, faith, miracle

Several passages seem to present faith as a *precondition* for miracles:

> 19 Then the disciples came to Jesus privately and said, “Why could we not cast it out?” 20 He said to them, “Because of your little faith. For truly, I say to you, **if you have faith like a grain of mustard seed, you will say to this mountain, ‘Move from here to there,’ and it will move, and nothing will be impossible for you**." (Matthew 17:19-20 ESV)

> 2 And if I have prophetic powers, and understand all mysteries and all knowledge, and **if I have all faith, so as to remove mountains**, but have not love, I am nothing. (1 Corinthians 13:2 ESV)

> 17 **And these signs will accompany those who believe**: in my name they will cast out demons; they will speak in new tongues; 18 they will pick up serpents with their hands; and if they drink any deadly poison, it will not hurt them; they will lay their hands on the sick, and they will recover.” (Mark 16:17-18 ESV)

However, other passages seem to present faith/belief as a *consequence* of miracles:

> Now when he was in Jerusalem at the Passover Feast, **many believed in his name when they saw the signs that he was doing**. (John 2:23 ESV)

> Yet **many of the people believed in him**. They said, “When the Christ appears, will he do **more signs** than this man has done?” (John 7:31 ESV)

> Then Moses answered, “But behold, they will not believe me or listen to my voice, for they will say, ‘The Lord did not appear to you.’” 2 The Lord said to him, “What is that in your hand?” He said, “A staff.” 3 And he said, “Throw it on the ground.” **So he threw it on the ground, and it became a serpent**, and Moses ran from it. 4 But the Lord said to Moses, “Put out your hand and catch it by the tail”—so he put out his hand and caught it, and it became a staff in his hand— 5 **“that they may believe that the Lord, the God of their fathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has appeared to you.”** 6 Again, the Lord said to him, “Put your hand inside your cloak.” And he put his hand inside his cloak, and when he took it out, behold, his hand was leprous like snow. 7 Then God said, “Put your hand back inside your cloak.” So he put his hand back inside his cloak, and when he took it out, behold, it was restored like the rest of his flesh. 8 **“If they will not believe you,” God said, “or listen to the first sign, they may believe the latter sign**. 9 **If they will not believe even these two signs or listen to your voice, you shall take some water from the Nile and pour it on the dry ground, and the water that you shall take from the Nile will become blood on the dry ground**.” (Exodus 4:1-9 ESV)

**Question**: Does faith precede miracles or do miracles precede faith?

Comment: “No signs will be given except the sign of Jonah” (Mat 16:4). Comes to mind too.

Comment: This is primarily a synthesis question. I don't think it's on-topic here. It's not even a contradiction question as none of the passages are directly contradictory. Obviously sometimes miracles lead to faith, and at other times God does miracles in the lives of those who already trust him.

Comment: So Jesus said to him, “Unless you see signs and wonders you will not believe.”  (John 4:48, ESV)

Comment: You seem to be conflating the *doing* of miracles and the *seeing* of miracles. This statement -- "*Several passages seem to present faith as a precondition for miracles*" -- is ambiguous. What do you mean by "miracles"? Do you mean the *viewing* of miracles or the *performing* of miracles? The passages you cite afterwards deal with the **performing** of miracles. While the passages you cite after this statement -- "*However, other passages seem to present faith/belief as a consequence of miracles*" -- deal with the **seeing** of miracles. Two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me affirm the dictum that Faith is not a work we do in order to earn God's favor.  Faith is simply trust in God.  There is nothing we can do to earn God's love because we already have it!  Miracles are performed at the behest and decision of Divine will, NOT the miracle worker.

**Now to the OP's question.**

The appendix below contains many examples of miracles, some of which were done to either create or strengthen the observer's faith.  However, the person performing these miracles exercised trust in God to work the miracle.

The OP's examples show this clearly:

- Matt 17:19, 20, 1 Cor 13:2, Mark 16:17, 18 are examples of God's people performing miracles under the inspiration of the Lord to do them
- Nebuchadnezzar, John the Baptist's followers and others had miracles done for them to create and strengthen their faith.

Therefore, the answer to the OP's question is simple - faith both follows and precedes miracles depending on the person involved and the will of the Holy Spirit.

**APPENDIX - Signs and Wonders**

The frequent Scriptural references to “signs and wonders” naturally fall into two obvious categories of the genuine and false.  It is clear from Matt 12:38 & 39, 16:1-4, Luke 11:16, John 4:48, 6:26, 30, that the scribes and Pharisees had trouble distinguishing the two.  See also 1 Cor 1:22, 14:22.

**Genuine**

The genuine signs and wonders attest their divine origin and serve to strengthen faith.

- John 2:11, 3:2, 4:54, 6:2, 10:41, 20:30 are all references to Jesus’ miracles.
- Acts 2:22, Mark 16:20 also refer to Jesus’ miracles.
- Matt 10:8, Mark 16:17, 20, Acts 2:22, 43, 4:30, 5:12, 6:8, 8:6, 13, 14:3, 15:12, 19:11, Rom 15:18, 19, 2 Cor 12:12, Heb 2:4 speak of the signs and wonders accompanying the apostles’ ministry.
- Ex 7:3, Num 14:11, Deut 6:22, 7:19, 10:21, 26:8, 29:3, 34:11, Neh 9:10, Job 5:8-11, Ps 105:27, 135:9, Isa 8:18, Jer 32:20, 21, Dan 6:27 recall the miracles done for ancient Israel, eg, to free them from Egypt.
- Dan 4:2, 34 records Nebuchadnezzar’s hymn of praise for God’s signs and wonders.
- In Luke 7:18-23, Jesus’ only answer to John the Baptist about Jesus’ identity (as Messiah) is to list His miracles: “the blind see, the lame walk, lepers are cleansed, the deaf hear, the dead are raised, and the poor are given the good tidings…”

**False or Lying Signs and Wonders**

Pseudo (false) signs and wonders are invariably produced in order to deceive the wicked.  That is, create faith in the wrong/false god or the false miracle worker.

- Matt 24:24, Mark 13:22 predict false signs and wonders performed by false Christs and false prophets
- 2 Thess 2:9 predicts the rise of the lawless one accompanied by false signs and wonders
- Rev 16:14 predicts that demons will perform false signs and wonders
- Rev 13:13, 14 19:20 predict that the great false prophet (third beast of the Beast Trinity) will perform false signs and wonders

It should be remembered that Deut 13:1-5 contains a stern warning about the veracity of signs and wonders to see if they are genuine.  Similarly, Matt 24:24 contains Jesus’ warning not to base one’s faith purely on Signs and Wonders.